# Differentiate between browser close and refresh event in browser?

Tags: angular, webbrowser-control

In **Angular** 4 application, I am dealing with one API call **to save details on browser close activity and refresh in database** . I am able to succeed in API call and save these details on browser close or refresh activity. **But can not able to differentiate those events whether its occurred due to browser close or refresh**. How to deal with that ? My current code in hostlistener of **app.component.ts** as follows

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
public beforeunloadHandler($event) {
    const browerLocation = $event.srcElement.location['href'];

    const browercloseinfo = {
        'ClientID': this.clientDetails.ClientID,
        'TestID': this.testData ? this.testData.TestID : 0,
        'BrowserLocation': browerLocation
    }

    if (this.router.url.indexOf('list') !== -1) {
        browercloseinfo.TestID = 0;
    } else {
        browercloseinfo.TestID = this.testData ? this.testData.TestID : 0;
    }

    const xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open('POST', url,false); // False used for making call 
    synchronously 
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
    xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(browercloseinfo));
}
```

These are the possible other ways I already tried but not useful in my case

```
 if (window.performance) {
     console.info("window.performance works fine on this browser");
 }
 if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
    console.info( "This page is reloaded" );
} else {
    console.info( "This page is not reloaded");
}
```

It's printing only refresh event on console though i had done browser close or refresh

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e)
{
   e = e || window.event;
   var y = e.pageY || e.clientY;
   if (y < 0) {
   console.log("Do You really Want to Close the window ?"
}
else {
  return "Refreshing this page can result in data loss."; 
  }
}
```

Its giving undefined value of Y variable  on click of refresh or close.

Please help me from my first code.

Answer (score 2):

You could store a value in `SessionStorage` as it will stay on browser refresh and disappear on a browser close. You could then check to see if the value exists

Comment: Agree..But not feasible in this case

Comment: how come its not feasible?